# How to convert LPBYTE to char */string in C++?

Tags: c++, string, char, lpbyte

How do I convert LPBYTE into char * or string? 
Specifically, I am calling EnumPrinterDataEx(), and taking the pData out of it, and want to convert that. When I try to convert using wcstombs(), it only gives the first character from the pData. But I wanted to know how the conversion can be done in general.

Thanks

Edit:
After getting the pData, I made a new variable of LPWSTR and then converted this into a char * using wcstombs, and it all worked well. Thanks!

Comment: Well, this depends on the encoding of the data! You'll have to do some string sniffing to guess if it's UTF-8 or UTF-16 or something more esoteric...

Answer (score 1):

if pData points to a string than it will be ANSI or Unicode null terminated string (depending on EnumPrinterDataEx function version) - so you can simply cast it:

```
(char*)pData;
(LPTSTR)pData;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried it both ways, but
(char *) gives only the first character.
(LPTSTR) gives some garbage value, or might not be garbage but something I have no clue of what it is.

Comment: Are you sure pData points to string? Can you view memory pointed by pData. What is the value of (char*)pData[0], (char*)pData[1]...Try also (wchar_t*)pData.

Comment: It crashes for (char *)pData[0], (char *)pData[2]..
And (wchar_t*)pData returns some garbage value.
The actual value of pData when I do wprintf() is of the form "AB1CD-E2FGH"

Comment: What is the value of cbData. You should be able to view up to (char*)pData[cbData-1] is this not true than your pData is not pointing to valid memory

Comment: cbData is 58. Although as you above said, I converted into LPWSTR, and then changed it to char * using wcstombs, and then it all worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your string is not multi-byte, so you have a wide string. Instead of manipulating it with common functions, use the [**wide**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/) versions, `wcslen` for example.

If conversion to a `char*` is required, then use [`wcstombs`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/wcstombs/), like this:

```
#include <cstdlib>

size_t len = wcslen(input) * 2 + 1;
char * target = new char[len];
memset(target, 0, len);
if (wcstombs(target, input, len) == len) target[len - 1] = '\0';
```